# Notice: Undefined index: dateReserve

Tags: php, mysql

**how to use data in table for php operator**
i search and read a lot of code but i dont see any one similar to mine but here i hope someone can help me thanks

i having trouble of how to get the value in table mysql to php

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['userName'];
$available = "available";
$unavailable = "unavailable";
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT dateReserve from reservation where reserveBy = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['userName']));
// this is my problem i cant get the value of dateReserve in my table
$dReserve = $_POST['dateReserve']; 
$expired = date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dReserve))."+ 3 day"));
if (date("Y-m-d") < $expired) {
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("UPDATE books SET bookStatus=:bav WHERE id=:uid");
 $stmt->bindParam(':bav',$available);
 $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
 $stmt->execute();
}else{
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("UPDATE books SET bookStatus=:bua WHERE id=:uid");
 $stmt->bindParam(':bua',$unavailable);
 $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
 $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
...
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT dateReserve from reservation where reserveBy = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['userName']));
// this is my problem i cant get the value of dateReserve in my table
$dReserve = $_POST['dateReserve']; 
...
```

do this

```
...

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT dateReserve from reservation where reserveBy = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['userName']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($dReserve);

/* Fetch the value */
$stmt -> fetch();

/* Close statement */
$stmt -> close();
...
```

There is no way you can use $_POST there, it has no business there

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::get_result()

Comment: try the updated code, i noticed some other errors in your source